# Splash screen in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, splash-screen

Please suggest me that how to create splash screen in iphone for some interval. i have tried to update in info.plist by creating a new resources Launch image But not working.
I have tried this

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "SignIn.h"
#import "Splash.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window=[[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];
    Splash *splash=[[Splash alloc]initWithNibName:@"Splash" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController=splash;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  sleep(3);
    SignIn *signIn=[[SignIn alloc]initWithNibName:@"SignIn" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController=signIn;
    return YES;
    }
```

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-splash-screen-in-your-ios-app/

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: added image in info.plist but not working

Comment: Do some google before you ask question like this. Possible duplicate of [Displaying splash screen for longer than default seconds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618163/displaying-splash-screen-for-longer-than-default-seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To present a view controller automatically after sometime add `NSTimer` in `viewDidLoad` of the splash screen controller which you are presenting.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

//NSTimer calling Method B
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0f 
target:self selector:@selector(methodB:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void) methodB:(NSTimer *)timer
{
//Present next view controller.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your own view controller with image view, which will also help you to do some preprocess for your app like check internet connectivity, download and save data required every time in app.

Comment: If i add new viewcontroller as a root view controller then how it will move or navigate automatically after some time.

Comment: As Rahul said you can set timer or if have to do some check at start you can do that and then switch to main view controller