# How to display a launch image until my webview load ends?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have a LaunchImage asset for displaying a launch screen. My problem is after launch image disappearing, the `webview` of my initial view controller starts to load contents.

So, how to display my launch image until my webview load ends?

My configuration:

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618163/displaying-splash-screen-for-longer-than-default-seconds. check this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify the **Launch Screen** timer or anything related to "how long it should show". It is not in your control.

1: Add delegate method to your `UIWebView` [webViewDidFinishLoad(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate/1617969-webviewdidfinishload)

2: Show a Copy of your "Launch Screen" as an `UIImageView` or a custom `UIView`. And `hide` it when the delegate method fires of as finished loading.

> **Note** In apps that run in iOS 8 and later, use the WKWebView class
>   instead of using UIWebView. Additionally, consider setting the
>   WKPreferences property javaScriptEnabled to false if you render files
>   that are not supposed to run JavaScript.

For `WKWebView` delegate:

[webView(_:didFinish:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview)

Comment: Thanks. But I got another question with your method: how to convert my launch image resource to a proper image resource which fits different screen size? is it possible to display a launch image resource with an image view?

Comment: @Sayakiss It is better if you create a custom UIView, add the same image as your launchscreen, and add a UIActivityIndicator to show that the view is loading, otherwise the user might think it has crashed or is stuck.

Comment: `add the same image as your launchscreen`: You know, an image resource comes with only 3 images(1x,2x,3x), but there are more than 10 images in my launch image resource, how can I select the proper image for different screen size?

Comment: @Sayakiss Your 10 launchscreen images have different width/height, but I guess the images is not full size width and height? Maybe you have a background color to fill the background and your image is only centered, then you only need 1x-2x-3x. Thats the only way to do it and the only supported method. Otherwise for a **custom method** you must do calculations on screenwidth and height and programmatically add the correct PNG file depending on your calculated height and width of the screen, i don't recommend this is very ugly code. You should use 1x2x3x as designed if possible.

Comment: @Sayakiss Also note my answer, switch to WKWebView , UIWebView has alot of bugs and memory problems, and is very slow compared to WKWebView.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will check it out. As for `WKWebView`, I have tried `WKWebView` but failed with some issues. I will open another SO post for those issues and then I will comment here to notice you...

Comment: I just wonder, how could you figure out it's `UIWebView` rather `WKWebView`? I don't mention it's `UIWebView` in my question...

Comment: @Sayakiss Usually when people write "webview" in the question, they indicate the use of UIWebView, otherwise when using WKWebView, people tend to specifically write it :) Was just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have control about the launch appearence time. However you can create your own `UIImageView` covering the screen with the same launch image and remove it once the `UIWebView` is done loading

Comment: Thanks. But I got another question with your method: how to convert my launch image resource to a proper image resource which fits different screen size? is it possible to display a launch image resource with an image view?

Comment: If its an image file or xib you can use it exactly as it is being used in the launch screen. The launch screen is just a view displaying an image. so just mimic the same. Regarding screen sizes if the launch image fits them all then it will fit if you do it manually.

Comment: `If it's an image file or xib`: it's a `LaunchImage` resource(see the picture in my question)

Answer (score 0):

You should try delegate methods of `UIWebView` :-

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

And use UIImageView (which contains your launch image), keep showing it till your UIWebView gets loaded completely.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a separate UIImageView "similar" to your launch screen, you can instantiate a view controller as exactly the launch screen and use that.

```
let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Launch Screen", bundle: nil) // the storyboard of your launch screen
let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "launchScreen") // the storyboard id (remember to set it first!)

// present the vc
navigationController?.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

// when you're done loading
vc.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

However, note that this is not a very good practice, since you should let the user now that the app is actually doing something. Consider showing some kind of loading spinner or similar.