# How to hold splashscreen until process in app delegate is over?

Tags: ios, swift, splash-screen, appdelegate

In app delegate I put some func, I want the splashscreen waiting till the appdelegate finished its func. Now, my app immediately run initial view controller func and app delegate func together.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let email = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userEmail")
    if let email = email {
       reLogin()
    }else{
        buildNavigationDrawer()
    }// I want this execute first and run the initial view controller's after

    return true
}
```

How to do this? or is that a way to turn off the initial view controller?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5618163/2231063) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2459609/2231063) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553336/how-can-i-display-a-splash-screen-for-longer-on-an-iphone)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to keep the splash screen on screen until your app delegate is done processing `didFinishLaunchingWithOptoins`.  You could, however, make the first view of your app match the launch image.  Then, you can dismiss that first view when you're ready to show your content.

Comment: thanks for the suggest! never though the "match the launch image" thing

Answer (score 2):

You can't hold the splash screen for more than expected natively. You could show a similar view controller after the splash screen, but only if you manage a lot of data and you need a loading screen. Holding the splash screen is also prohibited from the Apple App Store guidelines.